# How to move edges, when you move nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, genealogytree

I'm new to all this, so please bear with me.

When I move the nodes for the family id=JK (BB2) the edge is not moving along with them. How can I get it to look like the family id=AK (BB1)?
[image: wierd familytree]

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
    \titlepage
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \genealogytree[
    template=formal graph,
    timeflow=right,
    %% edge settings
    edges={foreground={black,line width=0.5mm},    
        background={white,line width=1mm}},
]{  
        child[id=KAK]{
            g[id=AndersKristian,male,]{B_1}
        child[id=AK]{
            g[id=Anne,female]{BB_1}
            p[id=Klaus,male]{Y_1}
            c[id=Tobias,male]{O_1}
    }
        child[id=JK]{
            g[id=Jytte,female,tikz={xshift=20mm}]{BB_2}
            p[id=Kjell,male,tikz={xshift=20mm}]{Y_2}
            c[id=Hans,male,tikz={xshift=20mm}]{O_2}
         }
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To be honest, I do not know what's going on since on p. 48 of the manual it is written that "These final shiftings do not influence the auto-layout algorithm, but the edges move with the nodes." Naively I'd think that this implies that the edges would move with the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Shifting the nodes does also shift the connecting edges, but not the edge core position which remains at the appropriate generation level.

To also shift this position, you may use `edges shift` which is documented in Section 8.8 'Edges Shift' from Page 219 of the manual.

Alternatively, a phantom node could be added to simulate a generation jump, if this is the intention.

The following code shows both alternatives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[
    template=formal graph,
    timeflow=right,
    %% edge settings
    edges={foreground={black,line width=0.5mm},
        background={white,line width=1mm}},
]{
    child[id=KAK]{
            g[id=AndersKristian,male,]{B_1}
      child[id=AK]{
            g[id=Anne,female]{BB_1}
            p[id=Klaus,male]{Y_1}
            c[id=Tobias,male]{O_1}
      }
      child[id=JK,edges shift=-20mm]{
            g[id=Jytte,female,tikz={xshift=20mm}]{BB_2}
            p[id=Kjell,male,tikz={xshift=20mm}]{Y_2}
            c[id=Hans,male,tikz={xshift=20mm}]{O_2}
      }
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[
    template=formal graph,
    timeflow=right,
    %% edge settings
    edges={foreground={black,line width=0.5mm},
        background={white,line width=1mm},
        anchoring=center},
]{
    child[id=KAK]{
            g[id=AndersKristian,male,]{B_1}
      child[id=AK]{
            g[id=Anne,female]{BB_1}
            p[id=Klaus,male]{Y_1}
            c[id=Tobias,male]{O_1}
      }
      child
      {
        g[phantom*]{}
        child[id=JK]{
              g[id=Jytte,female]{BB_2}
              p[id=Kjell,male]{Y_2}
              c[id=Hans,male]{O_2}
        }
      }
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]